# How to design a structure that can lead user request to related app's view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am developing a web application which gets feedbacks from shifts in a factory by asking questions to employees and getting answers from them. Currently I am responsible for one area and it is called plastic injection. Afterwards plastic assembly, plastic connector and metal production areas will be in my list as well. We can consider areas as departments.

In frontend I am using Vue.js and there is no problem so far. Backend side I created an API using Django with Django REST Framework. The API has two apps. First one is called 'core' app. It handles authentication and only has User model. This app will have another models and logics for feature plans. Second and last one is called 'plastic_injection' app. It has necessary models to get feedbacks from shifts.

Problem I face shows up when I add another app for example 'plastic_assembly' or 'plastic_connector'. In frontend, users login then they answer some questions to send feedbacks of the shift they are inside of. At this point **I need a logic to know which app user is belong** to call endpoint of the app.

The reason I created different app for different plastic areas(departments) is eventhough its models and logics are nearly 90% same, the content(questions) they contain will be different. Also, there will be rating system for employees, teams and areas(departments) and so on.

I considered adding a column to User table to separate to call which endpoint but I don't think this is the proper way. Couldn't find anything by searching this problem in Google.

Project layout:

```
[project]
├── [project]
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── [core]
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   └── views.py
├── [plastic_injection]
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   └── views.py
├── [plastic_connector] # New app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

User model in 'core' app:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_director = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_chief = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_chief_assistant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_operator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_proxy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(default='user_images/default.jpg')
    date_left = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name() or self.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Kullanıcı'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kullanıcılar'
```

Operator model in 'plastic_injection' app:

```
class Operator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    point = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.user.is_active:
            return f'{self.team.name} - {self.area} - {self.user.__str__()}'
        return self.user.__str__()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Operatör'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Operatörler'
```

Note: 'plastic_connector' and 'plastic_assembly' apps will have nearly same Operator model.

Comment: From what I understand, you need a way to map each User to plastic_connector/plastic_injection etc. I think this would be handled from the front-end? 

I would personally go with a single app/model for the questions, and have there be a `type` differentiating field in the models.py where you could put in plastic_connector/plastic_injection etc. for each question

Then when it comes time for someone to take it, you just have them select what type of questions they want, and it serves that type of questions to them.

Comment: Or, their `type` is set when their account is created, and then used from there.

Comment: You understand right. By saying "adding a column to User table to separate to call which endpoint" I meant your opinion which is adding type. However I don't know if this is the proper way.

For me, problem starts in frontend. To handle mapping user requests to correct app's endpoint, I need to know where user has a relationship like foreign key, one to one or many to many in which app's model. It is guaranteed there will be only one because I designed it. Like you said I can add a type to User model then use it as endpoint reference but don't know if its the right way.

Comment: I think you would want to do a one-to-many relationship, where each type is mapped to many people. Could you post your models.py file so I can see how you have them setup?

Comment: I added models to main question. Every person will use User model to have an account. Some of them will be Operators to answer questions. Some of them will be managers to check questions. For n different areas(departments), I need to map their account to related app's endpoints so views can get its Operator and list the questions to be answered. Thats why I added is_operator, is_director to User model. If User is a director(manager), logic will be different.